# AR Geospatial creator anchor is attacked but gameobject always follows me

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am trying learn about ar application.

I'm using geospatial generator to place a game object at a specified position longitude, latitude, that game object has the `ARGeospatialCreatorAnchor` script attached.

I tried by putting latitude, longitude near me. After building on Android, I don't understand why the measured gameobject seems to just follow, instead of standing still.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF5Q7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar issue. I installed the latest version of arcore-extensions and it started working perfectly fine.